# How to turn cache off for specific URL in Symfony?

Tags: symfony, caching

How can I disable the cache for a specific URL?
I got for example my Administration panel in url:

`/admin/`

front is of course:

```
/
```

The problem is when someone updates e.g. page title, he needs to refresh 2-3 times to see the change in the list, how can I disable cache for all after `/admin` url?

Comment: maybe https://symfony.com/doc/current/http_cache.html ?

Comment: Symfony does not cache HTTP responses by default. Maybe also check your webserver config if it is activated there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Symfony does not cache HTTP responses by default.

Maybe check your webserver config if the Cache-Control/Expires directives are injected into the response there.